# can't find/click a specific button in selenium (instagram bot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I have been trying to make an instagram bot with multi function such as follow / login / unfollow / spam. I have some idea of how to make those function but I am facing a difficulty in logging in.
The bot write the username and password then it submit the bot succesfully login but when the "Save Your Login Info?" page occur my bot suppose to click "not now" it is giving error (either it cannot find that button or it couldn't click)

I have tried to fix it but couldn't come up with any solution. I have been trying to fix this for the pas 5 days please help me.

//Required chrome driver

**The source code**

```
def login():
        os.system("cls")
        directory= os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        chromedriverdirectory = os.path.join(directory, 'chromedriver.exe')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriverdirectory)

        os.system("cls")
        driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        time.sleep(5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//input[@name=\"username\"]"))\
                .send_keys((username))
        os.system("cls")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//input[@name=\"password\"]"))\
                .send_keys((password))
        os.system("cls")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')\
                .click()
        os.system("cls")
        time.sleep(4)

        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Not Now")]').click()
```

full code below

https://pastebin.com/eXnxQSez

[image: my error]

Comment: After the code 'driver.get("https://instagram.com")' can you please print 'driver.page_source' to check if you get the html as you expected

Comment: It is the html which I expected i guess but the problem is that it is unable to click i think or maybe even worst couldn't find it